# Logger и Log в Android

Tags: java, android, логирование

В библиотеке https://github.com/kochedykov/jlibmodbus/blob/master/src/com/invertor/modbus/Modbus.java
Используется логирование посредством `java.util.logging.Logger`

```
final static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Modbus.class.getName());
```

Я хочу приспособить эту библиотеку к своему Android-приложению. Как правильно реализовать связь между `Logger` и `android.util.Log`? Вообще надо использовать `Log` от Android в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В своем мультиплатформенной аппе, я это реализовал так:

1) Сначала пишем свой логгер, типа:

```
public class MyLogger {
    static MyLoggable myLoggable;

    public static void attachLogger(MyLoggable myLoggableInstance) {
        myLoggable=myLoggableInstance;
    }

    public static void info(String tag, String message, Throwable exception) {
        myLoggable.info(tag, message, exception);
    }
    public static void info(String tag, String message) {
        myLoggable.info(tag, message);
    }
    //blah-blah
}
```

Далее декларируем интерфейс, который можно будет прицепить к этому логгеру:

```
public interface MyLoggable {
    public void info(String tag, String message, Throwable exception);
    public void info(String tag, String message);
    public void warning(String tag, String message, Throwable exception);
    public void warning(String tag, String message);
    public void error(String tag, String message, Throwable exception);
    public void error(String tag, String message);
    public void verbose(String tag, String message, Throwable exception);
    public void verbose(String tag, String message);
    public void debug(String tag, String message, Throwable exception);
    public void debug(String tag, String message);
}
```

Теперь пишем класс, который является оберткой на стандартным Java логгером:

```
public class JavaUtilLogger implements MyLoggable {
    static final char TAB='\t';
    private java.util.Logger rootLogger;

    public JavaUtilLogger(String category) {
        rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(category);
    }


    @Override
    public void info(String tag, String message, Throwable exception) {
        rootLogger.log(Level.INFO, tag+TAB+message, exception);
    }

    //blah-blah
}
```

В случае Android обертка будет такой:

```
public class AndroidLogger implements MyLoggable {
    @Override
    public void info(String tag, String message, Throwable exception) {
        Log.i(tag, message, exception);
    }
    //blah-blah
}
```

Остается только "прицепить" нужный логгер в зависимости от ситуации:

```
MyLogger.attachLogger(new AndroidLogger()); //для платформы Android
MyLogger.attachLogger(new JavaUtilLogger(Modbus.class.getName())); //для plain Java
```

теперь все вызовы где встречается `java.util.Logger` меняем на свой `MyLogger` и все.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, всё гораздо проще:

```
final static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Modbus.class.getName());
log.addHandler(new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord logRecord) {
        Log.d("foo", logRecord.getMessage());
    }
    @Override
    public void flush() {}
    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {}
});
```